# Unable to get hasMany association

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I used commit [eaa1123](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/eaa11231062e93567c9a1406415c8f21c4792e6b) (ember) and [508479d](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/508479dee764c2e9926487131a5a4814cfda1bf6) (ember-data) to build the JS files.

I have the following JSON returned from my Rails backend, which is generated with [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) (0.6.0):

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 408,
      "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
      "body": "In at quo tempora provident nemo.",
      "comments": [
        {
          "id": 956,
          "body": "Quo incidunt eum dolorem."
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and the following Ember models:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment', {
    embedded: true
  })
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  post: DS.belongsTo('App.Post')
});
```

All look perfectly normal:

```
post = App.Post.find(408);
post.get('title')
// => "Lorem Ipsum"
```

However, I can't seem to get to the comments:

```
comments = post.get('comments')
comments.get('firstObject') instanceof App.Comment
// => true
comments.forEach(function(comment) {
  console.log(comment.get('body'))
})
//=> undefined
```

When I use:

```
comments.content
```

I get an Array that contain objects, so:

```
comments.content[0]
//=> { body: "Quo incidunt eum dolorem.", id: 956 }
```

but this is not what I expected.

It seems so obvious, so I must be doing something wrong.
As a side-effect: currently I'm not able to render my comments in a template in a easy way, so I hope someone can help me on this one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you used that commit it means you are on the latest ember-data revision, which is 11. Adding  **embedded: true**  to load an embedded association was deprecated a while back between revision 5 or 9, not too sure again.

If you are using the default restAdapter, you now need to define embedded loading as a mapping as shown below and not as an association option:

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});

App.store.adapter.serializer.map('App.Post', {
   comments: {embedded: 'load'}
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
   body: DS.attr('string'),
   post: DS.belongsTo('App.Post')
});
```

You can follow all the previous discussion on it through the links below:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/504#issuecomment-11256934
https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/430#issuecomment-10925506

Various fixes for loading embedded records: 
https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/541

**This not directly related but incase all i wrote above fails, then add this solution to the mix**
BelongsTo association are not materialized when using findAssociation and extractHasMany hooks for async HasMany: 
https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/525

**The internals for anyone who wants to quickly see where things are defined with respect to the call to 'App.store.adapter.serializer.map'**

When we called 'App.store.adapter.serializer.map', the call to serializer is defined on line 536 below and the map is online 696 in the 2nd link

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js#L536
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js#L696

On line 67 of the  **DS.RESTAdapter** which extends **DS.Adapter**, the **serializer property** is made to point to **DS.RESTSerializer** where additional functionality specific to the **RestAdapter** are added.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L67

Comment: Thanks a lot, that sure did help. Guess I lost track of the changes somewhere ;)