# How to get children for current object in ember route

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

The templates section in the Ember guides describes how to use the linkTo helper. However, I can't seem to find the answer to my following question:

I have a page displaying some properties of a Post object. The page contain a link 'Comments' that need to display the comments that belong to the current post.

```
// Router
App.Router.map(function(match) {
  match('/posts').to('posts', function(match) {
    match('/:post_id').to('post', function(match) {
      match('/').to('postIndex');
      match('/comments').to('comments');
    });
  });
});

// post template
...
{{#linkTo "comments"}}Comments{{/linkTo}}
...
{{outlet}}
```

How do I need to define my CommentsRoute to populate the content of the controller with the comments of the current post?

```
App.CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // I need to get the content of the postController here
    // this.controllerFor('post') seemed obvious, but doesn't work
    post = ????;
    post.get('comments')
  }
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the postController with `controllerFor` from within routes:

```
App.CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var controller = this.controllerFor('post');
    return controller.get('comments');
  }
});
```

Are you using ember-data? In that case, it might make sense to sideload the comments data when loading the post data. https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#revision-11

UPDATE: Chanted `get('comments')` to `get('comments.content')`

UPDATE: Reverted `get('comments')`

Comment: I tried `controllerFor` but when I loop through the comments in my template and access a comment's property, I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined'. Might be caused by what I described in my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170370/unable-to-get-hasmany-association). And: yes, I do sideload the comments. Thx for that.

Comment: And are the comments really stored in `controller.comments`? Could you post your models and controllers? (or do a jsFiddle)?

Comment: Never mind. I've seen the model in your other post. Have a look at my update.

Comment: The Uncaught TypeError was caused by the [deprecated code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170370/unable-to-get-hasmany-association) I used in the association.