# Embedded records in fixtures error: "Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to load fixtures into my app that has embedded records.

Loading the data from the server (using a `DS.RESTAdapter`) works, but it does not when I try to load them through the `DS.FixtureAdapter`.

**Models:**

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr('string')
  comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment')

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend
  text: DS.attr('string')
  # I'm not specifying DS.belongsTo('post') because comments could also exist 
  # with other objects.
  # Anyway, it does not work even with it.
```

**Adapter:**

```
App.Adapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend()
App.Adapter.map App.Post,
  comments:
    embedded: 'always'
```

**Store:**

```
App.store = DS.Store.create
  revision: 11
  adapter: App.Adapter.create()
```

**Fixtures:**

```
App.Comment.FIXTURES = []

App.Post.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: "1"
    title: "My post"
    comments: [{
      id: "1"
      text: "My first comment" 
    }, {
      id: "2"
      text: "My second comment"
    }]
  }
]
```

And in the **console**:

```
post = App.store.find(App.Post, 1);

comments = post.get("comments");
console.log(comments.get('length')); // => 1

firstComment = comments.get('firstObject');
console.log(firstComment.get('id')); // => undefined
console.log(firstComment.get('name')); // => TypeError: Cannot call method `hasOwnProperty` of undefined
```

I think this question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174921/embedded-hasmany-attribute-access-gives-typeerror-cannot-call-method-hasownpr), and maybe to [this pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/568).

*Ember version used:*

- ember-data on [master](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/4b35be22d84ca13c5e8e0e2cb7447ab21892b8b1)
- ember [v1.0.0-pre.2-311-g668783a](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/668783a620bc004daa063df72c3d84035be6888a)

**EDIT**

[Here is the JSFiddle that illustrate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/lcoq/4Zqvc/1/).
And I also wrote [a failing test here](https://github.com/lcoq/data/commit/e1064ae9898228ddb354bfa65a370125b6727e0a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, at first I was guessing fixtures without id, but no. Perhaps

```
App.Adapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend()
App.Adapter.map App.Product,
  groups:
    embedded: 'always'
```

should contain also App.Post embeds comments always ?

If this does not solve this issue, I suspect the fixture adapter does not ork well with embedded, and you have to define the comments too.

UPDATE: After a discussion with @tomdale, no changes will be put into the fixture adapter in order to make it work loading embedded records. So all I can propose is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Zqvc/9/

BTW, here is what exactly tom said:

> I do not believe that fixture adapter supports embedded records
>       is there a good reason why it would need to?
>       it also doesn't support underscored_property_names
>       the idea of the fixture adapter is not to mimic the JSON payload from the server
>       it is provide stub data in the format Ember Data expects
>       so relationships are not embedded, property names are camelCased, etc.`

Comment: I'm sorry, I made mistake while translating my real usage into a more "classic" usage. The `Adapter.map` already contains `comments` as always embedded in `App.Post`. I've updated my question. I really want to keep the same fixtures  as data sent by the server, so these fixtures can be used to describe the API specifications

Comment: Could you file a jsfiddle please ?

Comment: I've updated my question and added the JSFiddle and a failing test. I can make a PR for this failing test if you think this is a bug, but I do not know how to fix it. Anyway, thanks for your time :-)

Comment: Indeed, there should be a bug in the fixture adapter. I've not the time to try a lot, but I think in the fixtureAdapter.find() method, you should call adapter.didFindRecord(), or adapter.load(), because store.load() does not go through the associations

Comment: Is it possible to know why embedded records won't be handled by the fixture adapter? I believe it could be interesting to let fixtures match the server response. Anyway, I followed your advise, and found a solution: http://goo.gl/Eig4o, could it be a good idea to make a PR from it ?

Comment: I understand. I think this solution also let the possibility to write a DSL for loading fixtures, and make it easy to write them, as Ember does for everything :-) Thanks for this clarification!

Comment: any solution to embedded always with fixtures ?