# Ember.js Model with embedded object

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm going to query an API that return embedded objects in the response, so I'm simulating this with the fixture adapter. My data looks like this:

```
App.Deal.FIXTURES = [
      {id: 1, name: 'Deal 1', closed_time: '2012-04-01', value_in_cents: 342345, company: { id: 1, name: 'Google' }, user: { id: 2, full_name: 'Bob Smith' } },
      {id: 2, name: 'Deal 2', closed_time: '2012-04-01', value_in_cents: 342345, company: { id: 1, name: 'Google' }, user: { id: 2, full_name: 'Bob Smith' } }
]
```

Here's my models:

```
App.Deal = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  value_in_cents: DS.attr('number'),
  closed_time: DS.attr('date'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.User'),
  company: DS.belongsTo('App.Company')
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  full_name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Company = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I'm unsure of how to get at the `user` and `company` objects. I see the data via console:

```
App.Deal.find(1)
Class {store: Class, clientId: 2, _relationshipChanges: Object, _changesToSync: Object, id: "1"…}
__ember1365792240874: "ember329"
__ember1365792240874_meta: Meta
_changesToSync: Object
_data: Object
attributes: Object
belongsTo: Object
company: Object
id: 1
name: "Google"
__proto__: Object
```

But I can't do `App.Deal.find(1).get('user')`. Am I missing something?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174921/embedded-hasmany-attribute-access-gives-typeerror-cannot-call-method-hasownpr), or maybe the context is very similar

Comment: Ah..ok. configuring the adapter seemed to work like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320925/how-to-make-embedded-hasmany-relationships-work-with-ember-data/14324532#14324532

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following setup worked:

```
App.Adapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

App.Adapter.map('App.Deal', {
  user: {embedded: 'load'},
  company: {embedded: 'load'}
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  full_name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Company = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Deal = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  value_in_cents: DS.attr('number'),
  closed_time: DS.attr('date'),
  user: DS.belongsTo(App.User, {embedded: 'load'}),
  company: DS.belongsTo(App.Company, {embedded: 'load'})
});
```