# Ember.js data with associations

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm attempting to use the latest master branch of ember.js and ember-data.

Here's some details:

```
window.Links = Ember.Application.create();

Links.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: 'DS.RESTAdapter'
});

Links.List = DS.Model.extend({
  urls: DS.hasMany('Links.Url', { embedded: true })
});

Links.Url = DS.Model.extend({
  url: DS.attr('string'),
  list: DS.belongsTo('Links.List')
});
```

When I do the following in the console:

```
var list = Links.List.find("test");
```

The API returns the following:

```
{"list":{"id":"test","urls":[{"id":"44e5aa","url":"http://google.com"}]}}
```

I can do:

```
list.get("id") // => "test"
list.urls // => undefined
```

I can't seem to get the associations to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a lot of us are in the same boat -- this is very similar to [the issue I posted earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174921/embedded-hasmany-attribute-access-gives-typeerror-cannot-call-method-hasownpr) and [the one I referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170370/unable-to-get-hasmany-association). Hopefully that means we'll have a fix or definitive answer shortly!

You may want to try the following, as recommended by brg:

```
Links.Store.adapter.serializer.map('Links.List', {
   urls: {embedded: 'load'}
});
```

You would then of course remove your inline embedded statement. It didn't solve my problem, but it may in your case.

Note that there is also an issue with embedded belongsTo associations as documented [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/504).

Comment: Ugh. That didn't seem to work, but I get your point. Seems like things are heavily in flux and the documentation is just outdated. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @user577808 try the following - it worked for me:

    window.Links = Ember.Application.create();

    App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend()

    App.Adapter.map('Links.List', {
      urls: {'embedded': 'load'}
    });

    Links.Store = DS.Store.extend({
      revision: 11,
      adapter: App.Adapter.create()
    });

    Links.List = DS.Model.extend({
      urls: DS.hasMany('Links.Url')
    });

    Links.Url = DS.Model.extend({
      url: DS.attr('string'),
      list: DS.belongsTo('Links.List')
    });